# Field property proof

Tags: field-theory, order-theory, axioms, ordered-fields

I have tried quite a lot of "turn and twists" but I just can`t get around it. Here it is :

```
if x > y then x > z > y
```

for all $x,y$ in the partially ordered field $K$ exists such $z \in K$. For the real numbers f. e. that is perfectly clear but here I seem to believe that I don`t have enough info over $K$. Any thoughts, hints or suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Well if $\mathbb F_2$ can be partially ordered then this cannot be true in general.

Comment: @GregoryGrant but there says that "then **always** exists such $z$ "

Comment: @GregoryGrant: $x > y$ is false for any $x$ and $y$ in any partial order that makes $\Bbb{F}_2$ into a partially ordered field.

Comment: @RobArthan That's bizarre.

Comment: Why is it bizarre? The definition of a partially ordered field is designed so that if $x > 0$, then also $x + x > 0$ (and $x + x + x > 0$ etc.). The existence of a non-trivial partial order with this property implies that the field cannot have characteristic zero. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field for the full definitions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z = \frac{x+y}{2}$ (the field can't have characteristic $2$ except in the trivial case when $x > y$ is always false). Then $x > z > y$.

Comment: that was pretty fast +1

Comment: $\ddot{\smile}$